# Problem installing Ubuntu 22.10 in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, error-handling, 22.10

I keep getting stuck at this black screen when trying to install Ubuntu 22.10 on VirtualBox. When I try to set it up I go through the code and all that, but it just stops at the below screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and solved it by skipping unattended installation by clicking the highlighted checkbox:
[image]